# Scala, how to not use None

Tags: scala

I have a bit of code that I am checking with Scala Scapegoat. I am not sure how to refactor this code the way it wants.

```scala
def strToDouble(valueParam: Option[String]): Option[java.lang.Double] = {
  valueParam.map(value => {
    Try {
      Double.box(value.toDouble)
    }.recoverWith({
      case e: NumberFormatException => {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
        logger.warn("error parsing string to double", e)
        return None
      }
    }).getOrElse(null)
  })
}
```

Scapegoat is complaining about my use of `return` and the `getOrElse(null)`.  Unfortunately in this situation I can't figure out how to do what I want:

- convert the string to double, returning Option[Double]
- log an error if there is a parsing error
- return None in the case of parsing error

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but how is this related to Java programming? Scala may use the JVM, but doesn't use Java syntax.

Comment: `null` and `None` are not the same thing, and while I don't fully grasp what you're trying to do here, any function that mentions *both* `Option` and `null` is definitely doing something really fishy.

Comment: In addition to everything above. `null` is universally bad (in any and every language). Don't use it. Also don't use `return` in Scala. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @sinanspd I wasn't going to go that far, because I've gotten backlash on SO before from hardcore Java coders who swear by `null`. But... yeah, `null` is definitely terrible and never use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general in Scala, you never need to use `return`, and it has some surprising semantics so it's generally advised to *never* use `return`.

Instead of `return`, the result of a block expression (such as the body of a function) is the result of the last expression evaluated in the block.

I would write your code along these lines

```scala
valueParam.flatMap { value =>
  val attempt =
    Try {
      Double.box(value.toDouble)
    }

  attempt.recoverWith {
    case e: NumberFormatException =>
      val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
      logger.warn("error parsing string to double", e)
      attempt
  }.toOption
}
```

The first key difference is that since we're transforming an `Option` into another `Option`, and might sometimes turn a `Some` into a `None` (e.g. `Some("hello")`), `flatMap` is called for.

Saving the `Try[Double]` in a local `val` enables us to get around there not being a `foreach` equivalent on a failed `Try`, thus the `recoverWith` which results in the same `Try` after side-effecting.

At the end, we convert the `Try` into an `Option` with `toOption`.

`null` is generally never used in Scala, with `Option` preferred (and an `Option` which could be `null` is especially verboten, as it's virtually guaranteed to blow up).  If you have an `Option[java.lang.Double]` and need a possibly `null` `java.lang.Double` in order to work with a Java API, the `orNull` method on an `Option` is probably the most idiomatic thing to use.

I'm fairly sure that `scala.Double` is, on the JVM, a compiler-synthesized alias for `java.lang.Double`, so `Double.box` might not be needed.

Comment: Yeah, one may never need to call any of the `box` methods unless writing integration code with **Java** generic. - Also, I personally wouldn't use `recoverWith` to do a side-effecting logging, I would just use a partial pattern match-

Answer (score 2):

Everything that @Levi said. I just have a preference for `fold()` in place of `recooverWith()`.

```
import scala.util.Try

def strToDouble(valueParam: Option[String]): Option[Double] =
  valueParam.flatMap { value =>
    Try(value.toDouble).fold({
      case e:NumberFormatException =>
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
                     .warn("error parsing string to double", e)
        None
    }, Some(_))
  }
```